# Scrapy Crawl ValueError

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, pycharm

I am new to python and to scrapy. I followed a tutorial to have scrapy crawl quotes.toscrape.com.

I entered in the code exactly how it is in the tutorial, but I keep getting a `ValueError: invalid hostname`: when I run scrapy crawl quotes.  I am doing this in `Pycharm` on a `Mac` computer.

I tried doing single and double quotes around the `URL` in `start_urls = []`section but that did not fix the error.

This is what the code looks like:

```
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http: // quotes.toscrape.com /'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('title').extract()
        yield {'titletext':title}
```

It is supposed to be scraping the site for the title.

This is what the error looks like:

```
2019-11-08 12:52:42 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-11-08 12:52:42 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-11-08 12:52:42 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-11-08 12:52:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http:///robots.txt>: invalid hostname: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/newuser/PycharmProjects/ScrapyTutorial/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
ValueError: invalid hostname: 
2019-11-08 12:52:42 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http:///%20//%20quotes.toscrape.com%20/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/newuser/PycharmProjects/ScrapyTutorial/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 44, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request, spider=spider)))
ValueError: invalid hostname: 
2019-11-08 12:52:42 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: Could you share how you use the mentioned class?

Comment: Hi, it turns out the spaces in the url were throwing the code off per the comment below.  I'm exactly sure how the behind the scenes works with the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use **spaces** for URLs!

```
start_urls = [
    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
]
```